# partial search in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

Hi i have an array like below. I want to search partial data from this array.
for example: i want to search "New Delhi" then i got array where city = Delhi, and search "Raigad" then got array where city = Raigarh

```
Array(
    [56] => Array
        (
            [city] => Davangere
            [product_id] => 14
            [tier] => Tier 4
        )

    [57] => Array
        (
            [city] => Dehradun
            [product_id] => 14
            [tier] => Tier 3
        )

    [58] => Array
        (
            [city] => Delhi
            [product_id] => 14
            [tier] => Metro
        )

    [59] => Array
        (
            [city] => Delhi
            [product_id] => 14
            [tier] => Metro
        )
    [60] => Array
        (
            [city] => Raigarh
            [product_id] => 14
            [tier] => Metro
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Make use of [`similar_text`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) to attain this -

```
$finalArray = array();
$searchString = "New Delhi";

//Loop through your array
foreach ($your_array as $key => $value) {
  similar_text($searchString, $value['city'], $percentageSimilarity);
  //if percentage similarity between the text is above 70%, add to to our final array
  if ($percentageSimilarity > 70) {
    $finalArray[$key] = $value;
  }
}

var_dump($finalArray);
```

Works for Delhi and Raigarh.

Comment: Didn't know this existed. But isn't it supposed to be `$finalArray[$key] = $value;`?

Comment: Better than using `soundex()` or `metaphone()` in this case.

Comment: yes this is okey, but not works for Raipur and Raigarh, and similar city names